# Требуется ли запятая перед "как" в данном случае?

Tags: запятые, как

"Жить как в сказке, не тужить..."

Answer (score 1):

***Жить как в скАзке, не тужИть...***

Оборот ***как в сказке*** может обособляться или не обособляться, это зависит от структуры конкретного предложения.

В данном случае оборот является **необособленным обстоятельством** и тесно связан со сказуемым: ударение падает на оборот, но не падает на глагол.

Пример:  Если бы с бюрократизмом можно было покончить исключительно введением новых законов, мы бы давно уже **жили как в скАзке**. // «Известия», 2002.02.11]

В других случаях, когда оборот используется **как сравнение,** он обособляется. Тогда ударение падает и на оборот, и на предшествующее слово, например:

...а прямо перед ними зеленел спокОйный, **как в скАзке**, ровный лужок, поросший невысокой травкой [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 2 (1978)]

Человек должен начать жить в обратную стОрону, **как в скАзке.**  [Токарева Виктория. Своя правда // «Новый Мир», 2002]